# Capistrano migrates to development database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, production-environment, capistrano3

I have a strange issue... I deploy my app using Capistrano (using pagespeed, nginx, unicorn). The strange is that my app is running on a Production database on the server (is correct), BUT Capistrano makes all the migrations to the DEVELOPMENT database on the server (there are 2 databases, as I understand there should be only Production database and all manipulations should be with it)... And i can not understand why...

I do not understand... why it tries to create a development database on my server? ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  database "foreignernetwork_development" does not exist (before I created it manually, but now I see is my problem and I try to find out how to make it was foreignernetwork_production)... Could you advise me what could be a reason?

My files:

deploy.rb

```
set :application, "[FILTERED]"

set :log_level, :info

set :scm, :git
# important! https, not ssh
set :repo_url,  "https://github.com/myname/[FILTERED].git"
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/[FILTERED]"
set :user, "deployuser"
set :keep_releases, 5

set :ssh_options, {
  forward_agent: true,
  # important! your current ssh port
  port: 12531
}

set :rbenv_type, :system
#important! change to your current version
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.2.2'
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)}
RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails}
set :rbenv_roles, :all

#set :rbenv_custom_path, '/usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv'
#set :use_sudo, true

SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake]  = "bundle exec rake"
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rails] = "bundle exec rails"

set :linked_files, %w{.env}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp public/assets public/sites public/system}

set :file_permissions_roles, :all
set :file_permissions_paths, ["/usr/local/rbenv"]
set :file_permissions_users, ["deployuser"]
set :file_permissions_chmod_mode, "0770"

after "deploy:updated", "deploy:set_permissions:chmod"
```

production.rb

```
set :stage, :production


server "[FILTERED].com", user: "deployuser", roles: %w{web app db}
# Important! set your branch from git!
set :branch, "master"
set :nginx_server_name, "[FILTERED].com"

set :nginx_use_spdy, false
set :nginx_ssl_certificate, "[FILTERED].pem"
set :nginx_ssl_certificate_key, "[FILTERED].key"

set :nginx_enable_pagespeed, true
set :nginx_pagespeed_enabled_filters, "lazyload_images"

set :unicorn_workers, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your missing `rails_env` in your `deploy.rb`, Try adding this line:

```
set :rails_env, 'production'
```

You can find the this in the README on the capistrano/rails Github page https://github.com/capistrano/rails

Basically what it does is prefix the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable to most (if not all) rails commands on the server.

You could also add this to a dot file on the server (like `~/.bashrc`):

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
```

Or if you wanted it set for all user accounts on the server add this to `/etc/environment` (works on Debian anyway):

```
RAILS_ENV=production
```

*NOTE: you don't put `export` in `/etc/environment`*

Personally I set it in `deploy.rb` and `/etc/environment` on the server as I know I never want to use anything other then production there.